# Helm Add values with --set command and extend given chart when using templates

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Structure like this:

```
chart.yaml
values.yaml
templates/
|__deploymentconfig.yaml
```

Usage: `helm install demo --dry-run --debug -f values.yaml`

What i like to do is, to add an `environment variable` with the `--set` command on `helm install` after the template has filled the yaml.

Dummy Command like this (not working):
`helm install demo ... -f values.yaml --set ???env[0].name=MyEnvVar`

Resulting deployment config should look like this:

```bash
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        env:
          - name: MyEnvVar
            value: Hello
```

What do i need to set on the **???** part of the install command to get the desired variable in the deployment part of the manifest?

Comment: What's currently in the `templates/deploymentconfig.yaml` file to generate that `env:` block?  `helm install --set` can make configuration available in `.Values` in the template code, but it can't change the generated YAML on its own.

Comment: There is a .tdl file to fill the deploymentconfig.yaml.
Reason for the "--set" is that i want to add a test variable on a test deployment without changing the helm code directly.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the template code that creates the `env:` block?

Comment: I could, but that would be off topic. Its easy to fill the `env:` part with a value, but i would like to add an environment variable without touching the helm code (only using --set on CLI). Reason: No Test Code goes to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you clarify:

> I would like to add an environment variable without touching the Helm code (only using `--set` on CLI)

You can't use `helm install --set` to make any changes that aren't described in the template code.  If your chart says, for example,

```yaml
env:
  - name: SOME_VARIABLE
    value: {{ .Values.someValue | default "foo" }}
```

then you could `helm install --set someValue=bar` to change the one specific environment value, but your chart itself has no way to supply additional environment variables, and `--set` on its own can't change this.

> Reason: No Test Code goes to production.

You can still allow customizing the chart without breaking this rule.  If "is it production" controls a specific set of things, you can make that a deploy-time control

```yaml
env:
  - name: ENVIRONMENT
    value: {{ Values.environment | default "production" }}
```

```bash
helm install --set environment=development ...
```

Or you could provide an open-ended set of extension environment variables, expecting that to normally be empty

```yaml
env:
{{- with .Values.extraEnvironment }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 2 }}
{{- end }}
```

The corresponding `helm install --set` syntax for this would be trickier, but you could write a separate YAML file of deploy-time values to inject with `helm install -f`.

In principle you could use [post rendering](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering) to make arbitrary changes to the deployed YAML, and that could include adding environment variables.  That's a complex approach, though, and it leaves you in the situation of having tested something with modifications from the standard deployment; that might not be reproducible enough for many needs.